# The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework-4, objectcontext

I have an Error creatting relations whith EntityFramework 4.0

The changes to the database were committed successfully, but an error occurred while updating the object context. The ObjectContext might be in an inconsistent state.
 Inner exception message: Metadata information for the relationship 'CodeFirstNamespace.EventsIndex_Module' could not be retrieved. If mapping attributes are used,
 make sure that the EdmRelationshipAttribute for the relationship has been defined in the assembly.  When using convention-based mapping, metadata information for
 relationships between detached entities cannot be determined.
Parameter name: relationshipName

Comment: Are you using code first or not?  Did you create custom mappings of your tables, or are your entities 1-to-1 with the database tables?

Comment: Are you using the POCO approach?

Comment: Yes I'm using code first, yes i'm create custom mappings

Comment: I don't know POCO approach...

Answer (score 1):

There's probably a property in your entity class that's missing.

Comment: The problem is when added a foreing key to a class( the class module is in a project and EventIndex in another)

Comment: same problem here! any solution?http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17502470/errora-referential-integrity-constraint-violation-occurred-on-db-savechanges